# how to efficiently decode arrays to columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that produces results for every month of a year. In my dataframe I collect these results for different data columns. After that, I have a dataframe containing multiple columns with arrays as values. Now I want to "pivot" those columns to have each value in its own column.
For example, if a row  contains values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] in column 'A', I want to have twelve columns 'A_01', 'A_02', ..., 'A_12' that each contain one value from the array.

My current code is this:

```
    # create new columns
    columns_to_add = []
    column_count = len(columns_to_process)

    for _, row in df[columns_to_process].iterrows():
        columns_to_add += [[row[name][offset] if type(row[name]) == list else row[name]
                            for offset in range(array_len) for name in range(column_count)]]

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns_to_add,
                          columns=[name+'_'+str(offset+1) for offset in range(array_len)
                                   for name in columns_to_process],
                          index=df.index)  # make dataframe addendum
```

(note: some rows don't have any values, so I had to put the condition `if type() == list` into the iteration)

But this code is awfully slow. I believe there must be a much more elegant solution. Can you show me such a solution?

Comment: Just as a little side-tip... instead of `if type(row[name]) == list` it's preferrable to use `if isinstance(row[name], list)` . [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) with the [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor.

We'll use [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) as well to fix your column name format.

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] ]})

pd.DataFrame(df['A'].tolist()).rename(columns=lambda x: f'A_{x+1:0>2d}')
```

[out]

```
   A_01  A_02  A_03  A_04  A_05  A_06  A_07  A_08  A_09  A_10  A_11  A_12
0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
```

Comment: nice! I had to replace the NaN's in my data with empty arrays, but it is significantly faster than my manual implementation. Thank you!